# VSCode include .js extension with Quick FIx Auto Imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, ide

VSCode allows me to auto-import component references that have not yet been imported in one file but are detected in another by hovering over it and pressing `Quick Fix > Auto Import`.
However, it pastes the imports without an extension, i.e

```
import { Foo } from './Foo'
```

rather than

```
import { Foo } from './Foo.ts'
```

This breaks when I `tsc` compile my TS code into JS and run it using `node`, as `node` by default requires imports to explicitly say the extension.

Is there a way for me to change this so that all auto imports include the extension by default?